# Converting panda series to datetime

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a set of sentences from which I need to extract date of variable formats. After that I need to clean the data such as if only year is present I need to add 1 as date and 1 as month. For that I extracted the dates but to clean date series I need to convert it to date time. I am getting error while doing so.

```
import pandas as pd

date_sent = ["This is year 2019","on 9/95","on 7/27/2019 sjd sdkn","7/24/2019 dhd dskdh"]

df = pd.DataFrame(date_sent, columns=['text'])
df['dates'] = df['text'].str.findall(r'(?:\d{1,2})?/?(?:\d{2})?/?\d{2,4}')
#print(dates.head())
#df['dates'].str.replace(r'(*/*/\d\d)', lambda x: x.groups()[0][0]+1900)
#TRIED THIS TO ADD 1900 to a year if it is only yy but it snot working as well
df['dates']=pd.to_datetime(df['dates'].to_string())
#print(df['dates'])
```

Comment: Do you expect multiple matches per item? How do you want to treat `9/95`? `1/9/95` or `9/1/95`?

Comment: no only one match will be there per item. 95 to treat as 1995 and def format, mm/dd/yy

Comment: Try `df['dates'] = df['text'].str.extract(r'\b((?:\d{1,2}/)?(?:\d{2}/)?\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)\b')`, then `df['dates'] = df['dates'].str.replace(r'\b9\d\b', r'19\g<0>')` and then `df['dates']=pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])`. However, it will extract the first date from each row.

Comment: Or, use your way and `df['dates']=pd.to_datetime(df['dates'].to_string(), infer_datetime_format=True)`

Comment: When I used .extract((r'(?:\d{1,2})?/?(?:\d{2})?/?\d{2,4}')) I got error ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups. But when I used .extract(r'\b((?:\d{1,2}/)?(?:\d{2}/)?\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)\b') it was fine. Can you tell me why ?

Comment: `extract` requires a capturing group. Does anything from above work as expected?

Comment: Yes both of them worked fine. I am further checking with larger dataset. I can now change if needed. Thank you so much for your help. 

Just a quick question, if I used findall i would get list of values and I cant use it to replace to covert to datetime unless I first convert it to string. As this was the problem originally. How can I convert such list to be used as string. I tried to_string method

Comment: Show an example case with expected output **in the question**.

Comment: For the date  4/3/09,
using `df['dates'] = df['dates'].str.replace(r'([/ ]\d\d)\b', r'19\g<0>')` I am getting 4/319/09 but I should get 4/3/1909

Comment: Here, it is still unclear what format you want to get in the end. Please include the case with multiple matches in the string and provide exact expected output

Answer (score 1):

You may  use

```
df['dates'] = df['text'].str.extract(r'\b((?:\d{1,2}/)?(?:\d{2}/)?\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)\b')
df['dates'] = df['dates'].str.replace(r'\b9\d\b', r'19\g<0>')
df['dates']=pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
```

The first `\b((?:\d{1,2}/)?(?:\d{2}/)?\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)\b` regex matches:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `((?:\d{1,2}/)?(?:\d{2}/)?\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)` - Capturing group 1 (`Series.str.extract` requires at least one capturing group since it only returns captures):

  - `(?:\d{1,2}/)?` - an optional sequence of 1 or 2 digits and then `/`
  - `(?:\d{2}/)?` - an optional sequence of 2 digits and then `/`
  - `\d{2}` - two digits
  - `(?:\d{2})?` - an optional sequence of 2 digits.
- `\b` - word boundary

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RIKed4/2/).

The [second regex](https://regex101.com/r/RIKed4/1) normalizes the year parts: `\b9\d\b` matches a `9` digit and then any 1 digit as a whole word (with no digits, letters or `_` enclosing these two digits). Note the `\g<0>` in the replacement pattern is the backreference to the whole match value.

The `pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])` converts the column values to datetime values.